# How to get current element attributes from click event in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

lets say I have something like this:

```
'click #url_image': function(e) { 
  var className = $(this).attr("class");
  console.log(className);
}
```

"this" in meteor is the context of the current template, not the actual item which was clicked. how could I get the class or other attribute from the actual click event, in this case the class of #url_image?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
$(e.currentTarget).attr("class");
```

Answer (score 5):

Or if you want a no-jQuery solution:

```
e.currentTarget.getAttribute('class');
```