# get class from circle element

Tags: meteor, d3.js, spacebars

I'm using d3 to render circles that represent each of the elements in my database. Each circle ends up looking something like this:

```
<circle r="8" fill="#585858" stroke="#008db7" stroke-width="3" id="Node;R6AnePqKecNNe7dkr" class="R6AnePqKecNNe7dkr"></circle>
```

I can use the following to return "success" when any of the circles are clicked:

```
Template.tree.events({
  'click circle': function(){
    console.log("success")
  }
});
```

but instead of "success" I'd like to return the class of the circle that was clicked.

If I console.log(this) I get 'Object {}' so my instinct tells me to use this.class but that doesn't return anything.

Comment: `console.log(d3.select(this).attr("class"))`

Comment: give your function an input like `'click circle': function(d){` what does `console.log(d)` print?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I now get an error "Uncaught TypeError: node.getAttribute is not a function"

Comment: @echonax doing that doesn't change the output at all

Comment: So, we need more code than this to help you.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm using the code from the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469287/how-to-make-d3-directional-force-diagram-reactive-in-meteor) as a base and currently haven't changed much

Comment: never mind, I've found a solution! thanks for your answers they helped me rephrase my google queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310598/how-to-get-current-element-attributes-from-click-event-in-meteor) the following code solves the problem

```
Template.tree.events({
  'click circle': function(e){
    console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('class'))
  }
});
```